# How to change column names if they contain a period?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, names

I am trying to merge files that have the same columns but have different naming conventions. Some files have column names that contain a period ('.'), while others have columns name that does not contain a period.

Some of the files look like this:

| First.Name | Last.Name |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

While others look like this:

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

I only want to change the column names if the column names contain a period. How do I go about this?

This is a snippet of my code

```
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    if df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('.')].any() == True:
    df.rename(columns = {'First.Name':'First Name', 'Last.Name':'Last Name'})
    li.append(df)

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: just replace the dots in your loop after reading the file : `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(".","")` ? I dont think there is a need of the if and rename here

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check for `.`.

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("."," ", regex=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
dot_columns = [x for x in df.columns if '.' in x]
df = df.rename(columns={x: x.replace('.', ' ') for x in dot_columns})
```

Let me know if that works for you.